# Why does Google log-in with FirebaseUI not work?

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, firebaseui

I'm following [FirebaseUI official example](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/app) however when I try to test Google log-in option after selecting the Google account the app remains unresponsive. The logcat shows the following error:

```
2018-11-06 18:51:39.779 1929-1940/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
2018-11-06 18:51:39.780 1929-1940/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):2)
2018-11-06 18:51:39.780 1929-1940/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):2)
2018-11-06 18:51:39.895 1929-1940/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
2018-11-06 18:51:39.895 1929-1940/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):2)
2018-11-06 18:51:39.895 1929-1940/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):2)
2018-11-06 18:51:40.216 1929-1940/? W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
    java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
        at hol.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):13)
        at hol.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):61)
        at hol.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):23)
        at hoj.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):2)
        at hoj.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):9)
        at xfj.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):3)
        at cje.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:604)
        at dly.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):3)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
2018-11-06 18:51:40.216 1929-1940/? W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
2018-11-06 18:51:40.399 2513-5726/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
2018-11-06 18:51:40.400 2513-5726/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):2)
2018-11-06 18:51:40.400 2513-5726/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):2)
2018-11-06 18:51:40.650 2513-5726/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
2018-11-06 18:51:40.651 2513-5726/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):2)
2018-11-06 18:51:40.651 2513-5726/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14366022@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):2)
2018-11-06 18:51:40.975 2513-5726/? E/Volley: [502] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyDGPA5UVAhDEXzbDftSdn9-vCezXFvz3-w
2018-11-06 18:51:40.975 2513-8927/? I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED
2018-11-06 18:51:40.978 2513-8927/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
2018-11-06 18:51:40.978 2513-8927/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
2018-11-06 18:51:41.270 1386-1622/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 8924113 , only wrote 8770320
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I just had to enable the Google sign-in method in the Authentication tab of my Firebase project console.